# How to redirect domain and tail via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect my url (containing subdomain and tail) to an offsite link, such as:

from `order.mywebsite.com/location/` to an offsite location `www.url.com`.

What I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^order.mywebsite.com/location/
RewriteRule http://www.url.com [R]
```

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%{HTTP_HOST} string contains your domain name, it does not contain the path.

change :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^order.mywebsite.com/location
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^order.mywebsite.com$
```

REWRITE

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^order.mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^location$ http://www.url.com [R,L]
```

Comment: The OP's URL appears to end in a slash, so you might need to add a trailing slash to the pattern.